# Trying to compare data against table and if there are matches, multiply the value in a cell by a given variable in the table

Tags: excel

My data exists in a workbook across four different sheets, one of those sheets being where I keep a lot of the variables and lookup information.

While working in sheet2, column K; I need the formula in this column to compare the data in column F to the data in column G on Sheet4. If it finds a match, I need it to take the value from the row, but column H on Sheet4 and multiple it by the value in the column I on sheet2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula should do what you ask.

It assumes that you are starting in K2 and copying the formula down.

`=VLOOKUP($F2,Sheet4!G:H,2,False) * $I2`

The Vlookup returns the data from column H on sheet4 where columnG on Sheet4 is equal to "F2" on sheet2.  The the formula takes this number and multiplies it by "I2" on sheet2.

You can change the formula to what ever you want, if you want to subtract "I2" instead of multiplying then just change the '*' to '-' and so forth.

Comment: The tag was a mistake. I was clicking on recommended tags and did not pay enough attention.

Comment: Yes, the formula did exactly what I thought i needed it to. I just need to wrap my head around the logic to get the data I need.

Comment: Basically what i need to do is take the result of that formula and subtract the data in $I2 from it.

Comment: @Scott I have added some explanation.  Remember to mark as correct.

Comment: The issue is I want to take the value that your equation gives me then subtract the value in I2 from it, ideally without using another cell.

Comment: @scott then add `- $I2` to the end of the formula above.